# How to display an UDP connection?

Tags: linux, iptables, netstat, udp

`ss` and `netstat` seem to not be working.

Adobe Flash RTMFP protocol creates a lots of UDP connections. I want to know, who is connected to me.

I can see intense data-send traffic from the monitor.

I can observe UDP packets flowing through my network card and know their destination.

But I just can't get it from `netstat` or `ss`.

`netstat -n` only shows some tcp connections.
`ss -u` doesn't show useful information either.

I can confidently say I caught some UDP packets sent to LAN targets which appear in the arp cache on my computer, but I can see no LAN address in `netstat` or `ss`.

Comment: I think you know, that flash is an obsolete and not particularly wonderful thingy today, but there are some special circumstances in your case, making it unfortunately unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

UDP is a connectionless protocol. There are no persistent connections; that's what TCP is for. It's why you don;t see connections!

It's a bit like a text message versus a phone conversation. With UDP, a packet is lobbed onto the net in the hope it will get there. Each one is separate.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with TCP where a socket must be bound to a 4-tuple before data transfer starts, a UDP application can bind a socket to a local port and then send/receive traffic to/from anywhere using that one socket.

However iptables can track UDP "connections" to allow for stateful firewalling. So if you have the iptables connection tracking modules loaded you can view a list of UDP connections your system knows about at /proc/net/ip_conntrack . The format of the file is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034698/details-of-proc-net-ip-conntrack-nf-conntrack